# How to view HTML file's source code on Android?

Tags: html

I have to view my HTML file which I have loaded into my Android mobile from Gmail. I don't want view it as HTML page. I just want to view its source code and note it down.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "executed"? Is there Javascript embedded in the HTML file? Why not just open it with a text editor and remove any script?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little confusing. In this answer I am assuming you want to see the HTML code and not the webpage(which is obtained by parsing the said code).
First you need to find where on device is your html file located. Then you can use a file explorer like ES File Explorer/Pro to long tap the file and select OPEN AS-> TEXT to view the source code.